# Can bitmap object be save as PNG or JPEG file format

Tags: c#

Is C# bitmap supporting saving the object to JPEG or PNG file format?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Bitmap extends Image, therefore you can call: [`Image.Save (String, ImageFormat)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.save?view=netframework-4.8#System_Drawing_Image_Save_System_String_System_Drawing_Imaging_ImageFormat_). For example:

```
using System.Drawing
// ...

Bitmap img = new Bitmap("file.jpg");
img.Save("file.png", ImageFormat.Png); // ImageFormat.Jpeg, etc
```

Omitting the second argument and just calling `Image.Save(String)` will save the image as its [raw format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.rawformat).

Comment: Wrong one, he wants to specify the ImageFormat.

Comment: and where is that written ? ( the documentation doesnt specify it)

Comment: If you leave out the ImageFormat the routine defaults to png. Maybe that is why Tim Coopers suggestions works...

Answer (score 9):

In addition to last post (can't comment existing post since i'm new here)

File type is NOT based off of the extension.
Just try to do
 img.Save("result.bmp")
and 
Image.Save("result.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);

and you'll see that file sizes are dramatically different.

Comment: Similarly, file extensions in *general* do not affect anything but what program the OS uses to open them. They are just a part of the filename.