# How to create Image from any file with stream? I had "Out of Memory exception" with Image.Save

Tags: c#

```
var f = Image.FromFile("redo.none");
f.Save("blyad.png");
```

What I did wrong?

I tried to use `MappedMemoryFiles` and I created it, but I need to do picture.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should prefer using Bitmap class, as:

```cs
using System.Drawing
// ...

Bitmap img = new Bitmap("file.jpg");
img.Save("file.png", ImageFormat.Png); // ImageFormat.Jpeg, etc
```

see Tim Cooper answer: [Can bitmap object be save as PNG or JPEG file format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124713/can-bitmap-object-be-save-as-png-or-jpeg-file-format)

Comment: I know about Bitmap, but it is too small. Do you know somethink bigger all maybe some way to glue bitmaps?

Comment: I tested with a file of 25000 x 20000 px (91 Mo), but I don't have an error. I create a sample project here: https://github.com/kiwille/HugeImageSample